# How can i post a message into yammer group from c#

Tags: httpwebrequest, yammer

I am trying to post a message into a Yammer group from C# with restapi. I tried so many links available an its not working.

Can anyone provide the exact code for that.

All the codes partially available and I am stuck to proceed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick draft of how I do it;

```
public static string PostMessage(string data, int groupId, string accessToken)
{
    // Build request-URI
    var endpoint = "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json";

    var sb = new StringBuilder(endpoint);
    if (endpoint.Contains("?")) 
        sb.Append("&access_token=" + accessToken);
    else 
        sb.Append("?access_token=" + accessToken);

    var uri = new Uri(sb.ToString());
    var request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest; // Create the request
    if (request == null)
        result = "It failed.";

    // Add request properties
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    // Format data
    var dataArr = data.Split(' ');
    var postData = "body=" + String.Join("+", dataArr);
    postData += "&group_id=" + groupId;

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

    // Fire away, and read the response
    try
    {
        var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        var response = request.GetResponse();
        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        if (stream != null)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

            var response = reader.ReadToEnd();
            stream.Dispose();
            reader.Dispose();

            result = response;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        var response = e.Response;
        // Handle the exception.
    }

    return result; // Return JSON result
}
```

An important thing to notice with the request here is using the Authorization header in the request, and including the "Bearer " in there, rather than in the URL; which is no longer valid.

When it comes to posting to a group, you can see the use of "group_id" as body parameter of the POST.

Hope this helps! Best of luck.

**Edit:** [API documentation of messages.json](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/messages-json-post)